# Add a custom target to .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I want to add a custom target in my .csproj file.

The custom target will be :

`msbuild /t:assembleDebug`

This target will just build with the Debug mode.

I have already try to modify the .csproj file but no success.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Maybe show what you have tried? Otherwise this is quite a broad question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This target will just build with the Debug mode. I have already try to modify the .csproj file but no success.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="assembleDebug" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">

    <Message Text="This custom target will only be executed when configuration is debug" Importance="high"></Message>
  </Target>
```

With the condition `'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'`, the target will **only** be executed when configuration is `Debug`:

[image]

When you build it with the **Release** mode, this custom target will **not** be executed:

```
msbuild "CustomTarget.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release /t:build;assembleDebug
```

**Update for comment:**

> Can I just call : msbuild /t:assembleDebug and this target will do the
>   same thing as msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug

`/p:Configuration=Release` is used to overwrite the default configuration on Visual Studio, if you just want call : msbuild /t:assembleDebug and this target will do the same thing as msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug, you should set the default configuration to Debug, then build it with the command `msbuild /t:assembleDebug`:

[image]

Then build it with that command line:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leo. But if I want to just call my target assembleDebug without specify the Configuration ?

Comment: Can I just call : `msbuild /t:assembleDebug` and this target will do the same thing as `msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug`

Comment: @leyh, of course you can. please check my updated answer for details.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a11c23907d6e00db0aba5706bed1d900 as you can see my project is set to Debug.
And when I use the command line : `msbuild Epicture.csproj /t:assembleDebug` I have : https://gyazo.com/88e423c8976ccb5da03caf0aa4494eba
The project is really builded ? That's not the same when I use `msbuild Epicture.csproj /t:build;assembleDebug`

Comment: @leyh, It should not be really built, It just executed the custom target, so you should using the command line `msbuild Epicture.csproj /t:build;assembleDebug`. You do not want use this command:`msbuild Epicture.csproj /t:build;assembleDebug`? If yes, you just need make that custom target depend on the default target Build: `<Target Name="assembleDebug" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " DependsOnTargets="Build">`

Comment: Thank you Leo ! That's exactly what I want.